# what is the difference between - and NOT operator in Lucene?

Tags: java, lucene, operators

In the [query syntax of Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_9_1/queryparsersyntax.html) it is said the following:

```
The NOT operator excludes documents that contain the term after NOT.
...
The "-" or prohibit operator excludes documents that contain 
the term after the "-" symbol
```

I think the difference is that the - operator can be used alone, which is not the case for NOT. Is that it?

Answer (score 4):

There is a very subtle difference. Take a look at this long thread on ["Getting a Better Understanding of Lucene's Search Operators"](http://www.mail-archive.com/java-user@lucene.apache.org/msg11783.html) which should hopefully answer your question.

Comment: To prevent link staleness (or whatever the SO term is), you should copy the important parts that answer the question from the link into your answer.

Answer (score 2):

**Quick answer:**

There is no difference between the behavior of the `-` (prohibit) operator and the `NOT` operator. The documentation does not make this especially clear, I think.

`NOT` is a synonym for `-`, here.

This can be demonstrated with some tests, summarized below.

See also the extract at the end of this answer for a summary which does a great job of distilling various points about the Lucene classic query parser.

Probably the most important point to take away is that the `AND`, `OR`, and `NOT` operators are not the same as "traditional" boolean operators. They are subtly different. This is because Lucene's classic query parser is only partially reliant on boolean operations - specifically, whether a document should receive a score or not. Beyond that, operators can be used in distinctly "non-boolean" ways, to affect how documents are scored relative to each other.

This makes sense, given Lucene's purpose of showing results *in order of relevance*.

---

**Test inputs:**

I am using:

- Lucene 8.9.0
- the `StandardAnalyzer`
- a `TextField` named "body"
- the classic query parser
- the default query parser operator (`A B` means "A or B")
- the following 6 test documents:

0. apples
1. oranges
2. apples oranges
3. bananas
4. apples bananas
5. oranges bananas

See [here](https://lucene.apache.org/core/8_9_0/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/package-summary.html#package.description) for the official "classic query parser" syntax documentation.

---

**First test case: `A -B`**

My paraphrase: "*documents which contain A but cannot contain B*"

The following query strings...

```
apples -oranges
apples NOT oranges
apples OR -oranges
apples OR NOT oranges
```

...are all parsed to the same query, using `org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.QueryParser`. That query is:

```
body:apples -body:oranges
```

They therefore all generate the same hits:

```
doc = 0; score = 0.3648143
field = apples

doc = 4; score = 0.2772589
field = apples bananas
```

---

**Second test case: `-X`**

The following query strings...

```
-apples
 NOT apples
-anything
NOT anything
```

...are all parsed to the following 2 queries:

```
-body:apples
-body:anything
```

These queries always generate *no hits*, regardless of the data in the source documents.

This may be counterintuitive - especially `-anything`.

In the first case, the single clause `-body:apples` forces all documents containing `apples` to be given a score of zero. But now there are no more clauses in the query - and therefore there is *no additional information* which can be used to calculate any scores for the remaining documents. They therefore all stay at their initial state of "unscored". Therefore, no documents can be returned.

In the second case `-body:anything`, the overall logic is the same. After removing all the documents containing `anything` from scoring consideration (even if that means removing no documents at all), there is still no more information in the query which can be used for scoring purposes.

---

**Third test case: `A AND -B`**

The following query strings...

```
apples AND -oranges
apples AND NOT oranges
```

...are both parsed to the same query:

```
+body:apples -body:oranges
```

This is very similar to the first test case - and actually returns the same hits with the same score. This specific case is not significant when investigating the differences between `-` and `NOT`, since it gives the same results as test case 1.

Digression: A more interesting test case would be `A B` versus `+A B`, where there is a difference in results and scoring (`+A` forces `A` to be required). But that is outside the scope of this question.

---

**More Background**

Looking at the e-mail thread referred to in another answer, here is a copy of the [most relevant section](https://www.mail-archive.com/java-user@lucene.apache.org/msg11815.html), reproduced here for reference:

*begin copied section*

In a nutshell...

1. Lucene's `QueryParser` class does not parse boolean expressions -- it
   might look like it, but it does not.
2. Lucene's `BooleanQuery` clause does not model Boolean Queries ... it
   models aggregate queries.
3. the most native way to represent the options available in a lucene
   "BooleanQuery" as a string is with the +/- prefixes, where...

`+foo` ... means foo is a required clause and docs must match it

`-foo` ... means foo is prohibited clause and docs must not match it

`foo` ... means foo is an optional clause and docs that match it will
get score benefits for doing so.

4. in an attempt to make things easier for people who have
   simple needs, `QueryParser` "fakes" that it parses boolean expressions
   by interpreting `A AND B` as `+A +B`; `A OR B` as `A B` and `NOT A` as
   `-A`
5. if you change the default operator on `QueryParser` to be `AND` then
   things get more complicated, mainly because then `QueryParser` treats
   `A B` the same as `+A +B`
6. you should avoid thinking in terms of `AND`, `OR`, and `NOT` ... think in
   terms of `OPTIONAL`, `REQUIRED`, and `PROHIBITED` ... your life will be much
   easier: documentation will make more sense, conversations on the email
   list will be more synergistastic, wine will be sweeter, and food will
   taste better.

*end copied section*

Answer (score 1):

Long time back i read this somewhere... Something similar to your guess... :)

The NOT operator cannot be used with just one term. For example, the following search will return no results:

`NOT "jakarta apache"`

whereas the "-" or prohibit operator excludes documents that contain the term after the "-" symbol...

Hope this will be useful..